# Is using the Typescript infer keyword or using another type more performant?

Tags: typescript

I was reading the TS performance wiki's section on [naming complex types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Performance#naming-complex-types), and am wondering which of the following is more performant (meaning faster for the TS compiler to compute the final type): using the `infer` keyword and an `extends` check, or using another type and passing what *would* be the inferred type parameter to that type?

Given that using another type appears to not require an `extends` check at all, it leads me to believe that using another type, the TS compiler is indeed able to cache more "information" as the wiki suggests, but I wasn't able to find an up to date reference specifically about the `infer` keyword being used for this purpose. Thanks!

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIg9gWQIZkgEwCoAsCWA7AcwB4MoIAPYCPNAZygCUIBjOAJzSNuDfwIBooSPCAB8oqAF4oAbwBQURVADaAaSj4oAawgg4AMygYAugC4ja43IC+AbjlzQkKAGE4AWzAAbCtj4BJPC98CBIJaQAKBSUAehioVk8AVyooWg9oOGAsCDY0pMg2RO8cZiQqNCgnaBy2CGjFUgoqGno8JPcAI1yGqAB+WXb3cwAGa17zJspqOjSePl6BmW42cwAiNfGlKHM8CAA3HoBKMmnWjTx9XKgAOQgAdymW2aZWDi55wkFhMSg40+e9GYOWYWg09DqAEckjg6pV9OwqjkoME9lBul44PcoHgslU4GQ2Gx2HIBvBkKgIJhcIQiHdHqI5LsDrl7I5wNAAPpuTw+ch+WkYcJQXr-YopaDpdyZbLXWgFXLFYJlCpVDlQWr1bZPGZtDrdNiLQYdUZbJSTAG6ua8QhG5Y8dabCY4llsezVVweby+GnEIVSWCIFDoAXEblevmhsKiWx-eLNK3AlhgnBtPF7KlUoA)

```
type DoMappedThing<T extends Record<string, any>> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K]
};

type ComplexThingInline<T> = (
    // compute some other supercomplicated type here
    T extends number
    ? {num: 0}
    : T extends string
    ? {str: ""}
    : never
) extends infer NewT extends Record<string, any> // extends check is required for the line below not to error
? DoMappedThing<NewT>
: never;

type _ComplexThing<T> = 
    // compute some other supercomplicated type here
    T extends number
    ? {num: 0}
    : T extends string
    ? {str: ""}
    : never;
type ComplexThing<T> = DoMappedThing<_ComplexThing<T>>; // extends check is not needed
```

Comment: I don't know that there's any authoritative answer here if it's not documented.  Maybe someone who knows more about compiler details would know?  Personally I have nothing but hunches, which are not appropriate here, so, uh... good luck!